# how to figure out which radio button was selected?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 radio buttons on my page:

```
<input id="rb1" type="radio" name="rmode" />
<input id="rb2" type="radio" name="rmode" />
```

How can I figure out which one was selected using jquery?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [:radio](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) selector and also combine that with [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to get the checked radio element.

This should work for you:

```
$("input[name=rmode]:radio:checked");
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WFwqz/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
...
<input type="radio" name="sample" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="sample" value="2" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="sample" value="3" />
...

//javascript code

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    // displays the selected radio button in an alert box
    alert($('input[name=sample]:checked').val())
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should return which radio buttons are currently checked:

```
var id = $("input[@name=rmode]:checked").attr('id');
```

More information [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/checking-if-certain-radiobutton-is-checked). Hope that helps!

Comment: Sure, if you're using jQuery 1.2.6. It'll break in newer versions ;o)